# Ionic2 / Angular2: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular

I've got a question that has been bugging me for the last 24 hours and I can't seem to get my head around so any suggestions would be appreciated. I have a class as such:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-product-list',
    templateUrl: 'product-list.html'
})
export class ProductListPage {
    public detailPages: ProductDetailsPage[] = [];
    /* Also tried:
        public detailPages: ProductDetailsPage[] = new Array<ProductDetailsPage>();
        public detailPages: ProductDetailsPage[] = <ProductDetailsPage[]>[];
    */
    constructor( ... ) {
     /* Also tried it here:
        this.detailPages = [];
        and: 
        this.detailPages = new Array<ProductDetailsPage>();
        this.detailPages = <ProductDetailsPage[]>[];
    */
    }

    public register(page: ProductDetailsPage) {
        // This line gives an error: 
        // Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
        this.detailPages.push(page);
    }
}
```

I appreciate that the error means that the array hasn't been initialized but why not?

I've tried initializing it in the constructor but it still gives me the same error. So clearly I'm getting things all wrong but if you can't initialize things in the constructor then where on earth could I?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How and where do you call register method?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I was calling the register function from inside a *ngFor loop so it is exectuted from this scope. Which wasn't immediatly clear to me.

Thanks for any help regardles.

Cheers,

-- B